# how to set adobe reader pdf advanced printer option from commandline

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

is it possible to configure adobe reader advanced print options from commandline when printing. I want to print the pdf document as an image. There is a 'Print as an image' option in the adobe acrobat XI reader printer advanced option.